# Calling bash function in perl find replace

Tags: bash, perl, replace

I'm a scripting noob and trying to get this find/replace working that injects salt strings in a wp-config.php file, replacing multiple placeholders.

```
    #!/bin/bash -e
    function salt() {
        uniqSalt=$(cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()-_ []{}<>~\`+=,.;:/?|" | fold -w 64 | head -n 1)
        echo $uniqSalt
    }
    perl -pi -e "s/put your unique phrase here/$(salt)/g" wp-config.php
```

This works, but it only generates the salt once so they are all the same - of course it needs to generate it again for every match.

Is it possible to modify this to do what I want? Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need bash and unnecessary piping through multiple system utilities,

```
perl -i -pe'
  BEGIN {
    @chars = ("a" .. "z", "A" .. "Z", 0 .. 9);
    push @chars, split //, "!@#$%^&*()-_ []{}<>~\`+=,.;:/?|";
    sub salt { join "", map $chars[ rand @chars ], 1 .. 64 }
  }
  s/put your unique phrase here/salt()/ge
' wp-config.php
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks @Сухой27 , that's much more elegant.